# According to the Rambam, what color would most of the tzitzis strings be if the garment was all techeilet?

Tags: tzitzis, clothing, color, techeles

The majority opinion is that, when we had the tradition on *techeilet* (the wool-dyed-blue string on tzitzis), each corner of the garment would have 7 white strings and one *techeilet* string.

If I've heard correctly, Rambam has the interesting opinion that the 7 strings should match the color of the garment.  Red tallis means 7 red strings and 1 *techeilet* string.  (We don't follow the Rambam!)

But according to Rambam:

- If the garment was entirely *techeilet*, would it get 8 strings of *techeilet*?
- What if the garment was entirely *kala ilan* (indigo, the Gemara says it appears close enough to *techeilet* to fool people; it's also chemically identical to some of the *techeilet* formulations out there today)?  7 strings of pseduo-*techeilet* and one of real *techeilet*?

Comment: There must be a lumdishe way to show that this is actually what Korach was asking.

Comment: Don't give the krum-bagel-bears video guy any ideas ...

Comment: Maybe I did already. http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2AAOoGWZZ7A

Comment: Who says we don't follow the RaMBa"M? 
http://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/936342/jewish/Chapter-Two.htm

Comment: I believe Rav Nachum Rabinovitch of Maaleh Adumim also rules according to the Rambam on this one.

Comment: Who says that the "majority opinion" is to have only 1 string be white? I thought the Rambam was a "das yachid" and that many Rishonim hold to have either 2 or 4 strings...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

He says ([Hil. Tzitzis 2:8](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/rambam.aspx?rid=926)) that in that case you can make the "white" strings any color except black, because that's too similar in color to techeles. (Kesef Mishneh there adds that according to this, using the actual color of techeles - whether the real stuff, or indigo - would also be no good.)

Comment: He says any "dye" other than black; I assume leaving them white/natural is okay too?

Comment: Yes, that's how R' Yaakov ibn Chaviv (cited in Kesef Mishneh here) understands the Rambam.